# Azure.RequestFailedException: Cannot access source document location with the current permissions. Status: 200 (OK) ErrorCode: InvalidRequest

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-cognitive-services

I have two containers in Azure storage, in order to do translations

[image: Containers]

original and transcribed, they are containers, because I need to access them

I have a method, to upload my document

```
    public async Task<Uri> UploadToAzureBlobStorage(string FilePath) {

            ContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(ConectionString, Constants.AZURE_CONTAINER_ORIGINAL_DOCUMENT);

            var blob = ContainerClient.GetBlobClient(Path.GetFileName(FilePath));
            await blob.UploadAsync(FilePath, true);

            return new Uri($"https://transcribemedocs.blob.core.windows.net/original/{Path.GetFileName(FilePath)}");
        }
```

The document gets uploaded successfully

I have declared a method for translating the document

```
   public static async Task TranslatorAsync(Uri sourceUrl, Uri TargetUrl, string language = "en") {

            DocumentTranslationClient client = new(new Uri(Constants.ENDPOINT), new AzureKeyCredential(Constants.KEY));

            var input = new DocumentTranslationInput(sourceUrl, TargetUrl, language);

            DocumentTranslationOperation operation = await client.StartTranslationAsync(input);

            await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync();

        }
```

I got this error

> Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Cannot access source document location with the current permissions.
> Status: 200 (OK)
> ErrorCode: InvalidRequest

and when I go o the URL, I got this error

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Please change the following line of code:

```
return new Uri($"https://transcribemedocs.blob.core.windows.net/original{Path.GetFileName(FilePath)}");
```

to

```
return new Uri($"https://transcribemedocs.blob.core.windows.net/original/{Path.GetFileName(FilePath)}");
```

If you notice, you are missing a `/` after `original`.

Comment: I already change it and I get the same error

Comment: I only checked if I am able to download the blob by its URL and it was failing because of missing `/`.

Comment: It doset work, I deleted it and upload it again

`       return new Uri($"https://transcribemedocs.blob.core.windows.net/original/Path.GetFileName(FilePath)}");`

Comment: You're missing `{}` here - `https://transcribemedocs.blob.core.windows.net/original/Path.GetFileName(FilePath)`. Shouldn't it be `https://transcribemedocs.blob.core.windows.net/original/{Path.GetFileName(FilePath)}`?

Comment: Either way put it I have the same error, by the way, I am using {} to concatenate the sting

            return new Uri($"https://transcribemedocs.blob.core.windows.net/original/{Path.GetFileName(FilePath)}");`

will give me this

`https://transcribemedocs.blob.core.windows.net/original/Articulo 6 (1).docx`

Comment: Can you try uploading a file that does not have spaces in its name? I am wondering if you are getting this error because of that?

Comment: I tried with a file without spaes and the same thing

Comment: I noticed one more thing [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/document-translation/client-sdks?tabs=csharp#translate-a-document-or-batch-files). Based on the documentation, your source and destination URLs should be the SAS URLs for the blob container whereas you are using blob URLs. Can you try by following the documentation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248475/discussion-between-eduardo-gomez-and-gaurav-mantri).